# Change the default port of Kafka-rest

Tags: rest, port, apache-kafka, default

I am trying to send some metrics from an http client to kafka and hence exploring kafka-rest. My client itself uses and needs port 8082. I am trying to change the default port of kafka-rest service to be something other than 8082, but it doesnt seem to accept any changes I make to confluent-1.0/etc/kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties

Mainly I am not sure if I know the right key to set in this properties file. 
I tried simply specifying
port=8085

and/or

listeners=8085

But looking at the code:https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafkarest/KafkaRestConfig.java there seems to be no way to override this port. Is this correct? 
Appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/kafka-rest/docs/config.html

Answer (score 1):

Add `listeners=“http://0.0.0.0:8085“` in `/etc/kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties`. `port` property was deprecated.

Documentation - https://docs.confluent.io/5.2.0/kafka-rest/docs/config.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `port=8085` (or the port you want) to your `kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties`

Comment: The KafkaRestConfig in version 2.0.1 is hardcoded with port value 8082.

Comment: My bad, the port can be changed in the kafka-rest.properties but you have provide this file as the first argument when you run kafka-rest-start script.